How to fetch user's (my) public IP address inside AWS CloudShell?
I'm not looking for the public IP address of CloudShell; I know that I can find it out by hitting some external website.
I would like to find out what my public IP address is when I'm connected to CloudShell.
I'm connected to the internet. I've logged into AWS console and opened a new CloudShell session in a browser tab. On a different browser tab, of course, I could visit the external site and see my public IP address, but how do I do it from inside CloudShell?
Purpose: I want to do this programmatically so that one step in our process could be automated (adding the user's IP to security group).

You can do the same as what you did on the browser - Request an external service to check your public IP.
But, in the CloudShell case, you have to use another HTTP client like curl instead of a browser. And here is some examples:
curl https://httpbin.org/ip
curl icanhazip.com
curl ifconfig.me


I think the question is how they can find their laptop's/desktop's public IP address, from inside CloudShell. I don't think it's possible unless CloudShell exposes some sort of connected session information.

Sorry, that's not what I'm looking for. My first statement explicitly states it: "I'm not looking for the public IP address of CloudShell; I know that I can find it out by hitting some external website."
Like Mark B says, I want to find my laptop's / desktop's IP address (from which I'm browsing the CloudShell).
